# Add team services hosted nuget dependency using nuget package explorer

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, packaging, nuget-server

I'm trying to add a dependency to a nuget package that is hosted on team services aka TFS aka Visual Studio Online using Nuget Package Explorer (NPE) but it fails with a 401 exception as below:

[image]

Also note that I've tried both the v2 and v3 source urls and for v3 urls, Ive tried both with and without .json path.

The packages this packages depends on are part of the same intended feed. I can push packages to the feed and I can add the packages to projects using Manage Nuget Packages option in Visual Studio. I've run the `nuget add sources` command in order to be able to do this and I can see my user name and password in the global nuget.config file and I can see the feeds in package sources.

So I think I'm set up properly as far as everything else (Visual Studio / Package Manager Console)  goes re: authentciation.

This problem is specific to NPE. How do I get it to use my credentials to access the feed so I can add the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this since NPE only support Windows authentication (without login form) for now:

> WiteCastle commented on Apr 24
>
> How would one authenticate with a VSO
>   nuget feed?
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/27/announcing-package-management-support-for-vsotfs/
>
> 304NotModified commented on Apr 25
>
> Hi @WiteCastle , only Windows
>   authentication (without login form) is currently supported.

Refer to these issues for details:

1. [Fix credentials (Windows authentication) + fallback for legacy
   API](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/pull/49)
2. [Support publishing to servers that require authentication](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/issues/58)

Answer (score 0):

NuGet Package Explorer probably doesn't natively support the authentication needed to access NuGet feeds in Team Services (Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager extension handles this through the keychain in Visual Studio).

You should be able to get this working using the Personal Access Tokens or NuGet Auth Helper instructions in the [Package Management docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth).